# Is there a way to easily distinguish between taskbar windows for the same application?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

When I'm working in multiple projects in Visual Studio Code, it would be helpful to be able to distinguish between the different windows in the taskbar for the same application in Windows. Especially, since Visual Studio Code puts the current file name first in the name of the window instead of the workspace name. I've been using a Visual Studio Code extension that changes the color of the border within the app, but it's very hard to see from the preview in the taskbar. This would also be helpful with multiple windows in Chrome.

Example of multiple windows for the same application

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?  I could have sworn they introduce a feature with the most recent versions of Windows 10 that would allow you to provide the preview window a name.

Comment: You can and I tested this. But I not have Visual Studio to test, Otherwise, Windows 10 task bar shows me what I am working on.